# Guava jar giving continuous error while deployment

Tags: api, maven, guava, cloudera-manager

We are using guava-15.0.jar as part of cloudera-manager-api dependency version 6.3.0 in build.gradle file of cloudera-manager client module.

[Gradle-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24XAg.jpg)

But while deploying it is giving the below error -

"stderr": "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Objects$ToStringHelper\n\tat java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)\n\tat java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2729)\n\tat java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2003)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.getClassMethods(ClassUtil.java:1159)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethodCollector._addMemberMethods(AnnotatedMethodCollector.java:110)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethodCollector.collect(AnnotatedMethodCollector.java:42)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethodCollector.collectMethods(AnnotatedMethodCollector.java:33)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._methods(AnnotatedClass.java:365)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.memberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:305)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.findObjectIdInfo(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:302)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.findObjectIdInfo(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:433)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getObjectIdInfo(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:270)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.(BasicBeanDescription.java:131)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.forDeserialization(BasicBeanDescription.java:139)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:112)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:16)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig.introspect(DeserializationConfig.java:804)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:324)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:446)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:183)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handlePrimaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:653)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:489)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:293)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:446)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:183)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handlePrimaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:653)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:489)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:293)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:446)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:183)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handlePrimaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:653)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:489)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:293)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:479)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._prefetchRootDeserializer(ObjectReader.java:2094)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.forType(ObjectReader.java:681)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:802)\n\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1430)\n\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:472)\n\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:421)\n\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.readBody(AbstractClient.java:552)\n\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.handleResponse(ClientProxyImpl.java:1017)\n\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.doChainedInvocation(ClientProxyImpl.java:905)\n\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.invoke(ClientProxyImpl.java:345)\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.readClusters(Unknown Source)\n\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.service.CmService.getClusters(CmService.java:344)\n\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.service.CmService.getSingleCluster(CmService.java:352)\n\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.service.CmService.getSingleClusterDisplayName(CmService.java:369)\n\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.action.CmCommand.executeCommand(CmCommand.java:96)\n\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.action.CmCommand.main(CmCommand.java:83)\nCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Objects$ToStringHelper\n\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)\n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)\n\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)\n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)\n\t... 62 more", "stderr_lines": ["Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Objects$ToStringHelper", "\tat java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)", "\tat java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2729)", "\tat java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2003)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.getClassMethods(ClassUtil.java:1159)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethodCollector._addMemberMethods(AnnotatedMethodCollector.java:110)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethodCollector.collect(AnnotatedMethodCollector.java:42)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethodCollector.collectMethods(AnnotatedMethodCollector.java:33)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._methods(AnnotatedClass.java:365)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.memberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:305)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.findObjectIdInfo(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:302)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.findObjectIdInfo(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:433)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getObjectIdInfo(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:270)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.(BasicBeanDescription.java:131)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.forDeserialization(BasicBeanDescription.java:139)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:112)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:16)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig.introspect(DeserializationConfig.java:804)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:324)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:446)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:183)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handlePrimaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:653)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:489)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:293)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:446)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:183)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handlePrimaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:653)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:489)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:293)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:446)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:183)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handlePrimaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:653)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:489)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:293)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:479)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._prefetchRootDeserializer(ObjectReader.java:2094)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.forType(ObjectReader.java:681)", "\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:802)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1430)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:472)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:421)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.readBody(AbstractClient.java:552)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.handleResponse(ClientProxyImpl.java:1017)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.doChainedInvocation(ClientProxyImpl.java:905)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.invoke(ClientProxyImpl.java:345)", "\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.readClusters(Unknown Source)", "\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.service.CmService.getClusters(CmService.java:344)", "\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.service.CmService.getSingleCluster(CmService.java:352)", "\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.service.CmService.getSingleClusterDisplayName(CmService.java:369)", "\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.action.CmCommand.executeCommand(CmCommand.java:96)", "\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.action.CmCommand.main(CmCommand.java:83)", "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Objects$ToStringHelper", "\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)", "\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)", "\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)", "\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)", "\t... 62 more"],

We faced the above error even with guava-30.0-jre.

I tried deploying by excluding the above guava jar but that again gave error -

"stderr": "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader\n\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.service.CmService.connect(CmService.java:394)\n\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.action.CmCommand.executeCommand(CmCommand.java:95)\n\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.action.CmCommand.main(CmCommand.java:83)\nCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader\n\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)\n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)\n\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)\n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)\n\t... 3 more",
"stderr_lines": [
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader",
"\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.service.CmService.connect(CmService.java:394)",
"\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.action.CmCommand.executeCommand(CmCommand.java:95)",
"\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.action.CmCommand.main(CmCommand.java:83)",
"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader",
"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)",
"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)",
"\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)",
"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)",
"\t... 3 more"
],

Adding to this, please find the output for the below command-
and help us know if this is the cause of that error. if so what can we do to resolve it.
[Guava-runtime-dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOG79.jpg)

```
Dependency Tree-

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

compile - Dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'implementation ' instead).
+--- com.cloudera.api:cloudera-manager-api:6.3.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8 -> 2.13.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.8 -> 2.13.0.1/stax2-api-4.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8 -> 2.13.0ation/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.0com/cloudera/api/cloudera-manager-api/6.3.0/cloudera|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.9.8 -> 2.10.3
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.3 -> 2.13.0downloaded
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.3 -> 2.13.0
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.3 -> 2.13.0 (*)
|    |    +--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2 -> 2.3.3
|    |    |    \--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.2
|    |    \--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1 -> 1.2.2
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.9.8 -> 2.10.3
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:2.10.3
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.3 -> 2.13.0
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.3 -> 2.13.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.10.3 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-client:3.1.12 -> 3.4.4
|    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:3.4.4
|    |    |    \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.4.4
|    |    |         +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.4
|    |    |         |    +--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3 (*)
|    |    |         |    +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:2.3.4
|    |    |         |    +--- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:3.0.12
|    |    |         |    \--- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.2
|    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:6.2.6
|    |    |         |    \--- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.2.1
|    |    |         +--- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:2.2.5
|    |    |         \--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.4.4 (*)
|    |    \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:3.4.4
|    |         +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.4.4 (*)
|    |         +--- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:2.1.6
|    |         +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5
|    |         +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:3.4.4 (*)
|    |         \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-security:3.4.4
|    |              \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.4.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:14.0 -> 15.0
|    +--- joda-time:joda-time:2.1
|    +--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1
|    +--- com.webcohesion.enunciate:enunciate-core:2.7.0
|    |    +--- com.webcohesion.enunciate:enunciate-core-annotations:2.7.0
|    |    +--- com.webcohesion.enunciate:enunciate-javac-support:2.7.0
|    |    +--- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.10
|    |    |    +--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
|    |    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 -> 1.2
|    |    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2
|    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |    +--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5
|    |    +--- org.jgrapht:jgrapht-core:0.9.1
|    |    +--- org.reflections:reflections:0.9.9
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:15.0
|    |    |    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.18.2-GA
|    |    |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:2.0.1
|    |    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
|    +--- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.17
|    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.7.5
|         \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5 (*)
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.21
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21 -> 1.7.30
|    \--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
+--- com.github.stefanbirkner:system-rules:1.3.0
|    \--- junit:junit-dep:[4.9,) -> 4.11
|         \--- junit:junit:4.11
|              \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.4.2
|    +--- org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.0.5
|    \--- org.eclipse.persistence:commonj.sdo:2.1.1
+--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:2.7.7 -> 3.4.4 (*)
+--- org.json:json:20140107
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
+--- commonlibs:aes128-encryption:1.1.3
+--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13
|    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13
|    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.3 -> 2.13.0
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.0 (*)
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:2.10.3 (*)
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.10.3 (*)
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.10.3 (*)
\--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-client:3.4.4 (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.
```

Can you please suggest on what shall we do to resolve the above errors.

Regards,

Jessica Jindal

Comment: My assumption is that the defined repository does not contain the needed dependency because If I correctly remember the given repository is not up-to-date nor does contain everything needed..better check central repository...

Comment: Check your dependency tree and exclude older versions of Guava.

Comment: Hi @OlivierGrégoire,
Initially we were having latest version of guava only and we excluded this internal guava jar,but that also gave the same error.

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise,
Can you please explain me further on what shall i do?
As i checked the repository url, its working.

Comment: The given maven repository does not contain everything... check that repo...If you are in a corporate environment you should use an internal repositoy manager instead...

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, 
I have edited the question and added runtime dependency tree. Can you please check and suggest if that is the issue?

Comment: Your "dependency tree" is unusable because it's a picture and it's not complete. Please copy/paste it here.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, 
Is there any way to attach a file?

Comment: @JessicaJindal just copy/paste the content it in the question

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, i have edited the question. Can you please check that now.

Comment: It looks like the place where you deploy your app is already deploying a version of Guava, but with version < 10. Please check that, and try to figure out from there.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire,
Can you please clarify from where did you get the guava version less than 10. As i can see in the dependency tree that it is deploying guava-15 version.

Comment: The missing class is `CacheLoader`, which was introduced in Guava 10. Since the class can't be found, another and older version of Guava that doesn't have `CacheLoader` yet (including maybe the old name Google Commons) is on your classpath when you deploy. So that's why you should check your deployment environment.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, we got this class loader error when we excluded guava jar. So right now we dont have guava jar included in our build for deployment.